# Flutter Getx builder not updating UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm trying to use a GetX Builder in combination with a bool in the controller to display a loading spinner while fetching data and then the data afterwards.

Printing the update to the bool shows it finishes loading and changes the variable but the UI is never updated to reflect this.

**Controller**

```
class AuthController extends GetxController {

  //final RxBool isLoading = true.obs;
  //var isLoading = true.obs;

  final Rx<bool> isLoading = Rx<bool>(true);

  setLoading(bool status) {
    isLoading.value = status;
    print(isLoading.value);
    update();
  }


  fetchUserData() async {
    setLoading(true);
    _firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.authStateChanges());
    if (_auth.currentUser != null) {
      bool profileRetrieved =
          await FirestoreDB().getUserProfile(_auth.currentUser!.uid).then((_) {
        return true;
      });

      setLoading(!profileRetrieved);

    }
  }
}
```

**Profile Page**

```
class ProfileCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<AuthController>(
      init: AuthController(),
      initState: (_) => AuthController().fetchUserData(),
      builder: (controller) {
        if (controller.isLoading.value) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        return Container(...);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

That widget is called within another as part of the wider UI. Let me know if you'd need to see that and/or anything else.

As you can see I've tried different ways of setting up the bool and none of them seem to trigger a change of UI in the builder.

Probably doing something stupid but I've tried a few different approaches and looked around for people having similar problems but not been able to crack it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `isLoading` as a `Rx<bool>`. In that case you need to change `GetBuilder` into `GetX`. And no need to call `update()`.

- `GetBuilder` is for non-reactive, non-Rx, simple state management
- `GetX` is for reactive, Rx state management

Comment: Thank you!

I appreciate the clear explanation of what to use when as well as I was getting myself all tangled up with that at the end of the week and decided to give myself the weekend off and try again. Appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: Why? What's the problem? It's pretty much same as provider except without the need of context.

Comment: The answer saved my week.